# jquery slideToggle opens all divs instead of just the div that is required

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a page that can have a variable number of `<div>` the idea is people can click the + symbol which is an `<img>` then the div that is linked to the img tag will display.

I currently have:

PHP/HTML

```
$plus = '<img src="images/plus.png" class="clickme" width="20px" height="20px">';

$table .= '<div>'.$plus.'</div>';
$hidden .= '<div class"diary">-Content-</div>';
```

JS

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".clickme" ).click(function() {
        $( ".diary" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() { 
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

This obviously opens all divs and not just the one that is clicked on. I have looked at other similar questions on here and have tried a number of variations such as:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".clickme").click(function(){
         $(this).next(".diary").toggle();   
        });
});
```

However, when I try these it just stops working altogether. i.e. none of the divs slide up or down. I see the examples work on JS Fiddle but as soon as i apply it to my page I get nothing.
I am possibly doing something really dumb for it not to work but can't see what.
thanks for any help.

The HTML output should look like

```
<div>
    <div>
        <table>
            <img class="clickme">
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="diary">
        <table> content </table>
    </div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 1):

(based on tht HTML provided)
Best way would be to add an attribute with matching indexes to both elements

```
  <div>test toggle
    <div class="clickme" data-index="1">click me</div>
    <div class="toggle" id="obj_1">toggled field</div>
</div>
```

and then in the JQuery:

```
       $(function () {
            $(".clickme").click(function () {
                //get number from clicked element's attribute
                var index  =$(this).attr('data-index');
                //select element with id that matches index and toggle
                $('#obj_'+index).toggle();
            });
        })
```

Comment: see update to use `parent()`. didn't realize that they are siblings

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but like all the other examples i have tried to focus on one div, nothing moves. I cant work out whats going wrong

Comment: i tried with the .parent() update and still nothing changed, is there something that could block this from working?

Comment: what does your generated html look like? are you sure you are traversing the DOM correctly? I tried and its working

Comment: Yes sorry @M B i didnt mean to suggest your code didnt work just that when ever i try it it doesn't

Comment: yeah, your html is totally different. I will update the answer

Comment: This almost worked except it now only moves the first div. Is it because it is calling an id, are the id's supposed to change as each div occurs or is it because i am using an image tag instead of a div?

Comment: each repeat of the img and div should have an incrementing index so each img matches the div to toggle

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your code, i can see that the slideToggle call is maded on .diary class which is probably applied on each of your elements.

I suggest you to put your diary div inside the $plus div then use jquery children or simply give your .diary divs a unique id and use the id attribute for your 
toggle.

**EDIT**:

Here is a simple html output:

`<div class="clickme">
    <div class="diary">CONTENT HERE</div>
</div>`

Add this in the CSS:

`.clickme {
    background: url('images/plus.png') no-repeat top left;
    min-width: 20px;
    min-height: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}`

Script tag:

`<script>
    $(function() {
        $(".clickme").click(function() {
            $(this).children().slideToggle("slow");
        });
    });
 </script>`

Note that i'd let the diary class for your usage and styling purpose but it's not used anywhere.

Comment: Sorry maybe over simplified my answer, both the img tag and the .diary div are in another div that repeats a variable number of times, is this what you meant?